# pytorch: how to change batchsize during training?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, updatebatchsize

I want to change batchsize during traing loop. I have tried re-instantiate a new dataloader so that i change batchsize by change 'batchsize' parameter. But this will spend some time.

How can I change batchsize like below:

```
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # do sth here like traing model
        dataloader.setBatchsize(newBatchsize) #this what i want to do
```

in this paper: *Semi-Dynamic Load Balancing: Efficient Distributed
Learning in Non-Dedicated Environments* ,the author say that he change batchsize by custom `DataIter` and `BatchSampler`, but I have no idea how to do that.

Hope that colleagues and seniors can give some guidance

Comment: Your question is quite clear, which is good, but it is difficult to know why and how you are stuck. Is it the logic? Is it custom classes in python? Is it the dataloader logic of pytorch in general? Please add more details on *why* you feel stuck.

Comment: Create a custom loader and paste the code if it does not work as expected.